# Storing registration data android

Tags: android, xml, store

Android storage option like,

I want to store the different users 
registration details in a single ".xml" 
file with same set of tags.I want the filename 
to be "Users" the details of each users details
 have to get stored in that file. The set of 
tags will be username,address,dob,
mobile no etc..every users information have to be
 stored in the users file with the same set of tags 
repeatedly.when the user click on the update button 
these details should get stored in that file.

If somebody know  , please help me thank you.........

Something like this

```
</Entry>
<Start_Date>27-09-16</Start_Date>
<End_Date>29-09-16</End_Date>
<Customer_File>1_16A1.xml</Customer_File>
<Name>Mohan</Name>

<Start_Date>27-09-16</Start_Date>
<End_Date>29-09-16</End_Date>
<Customer_File>1_16A1.xml</Customer_File>
<Name>Raj</Name>
</Entry>
```

Each user details must get stored like the above format. The particular user detail should get added to the existing details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code snippet to create users.xml file and write user data into it:

```
final String xmlFile = "users";
String userName = "username";
String password = "password";
try {
FileOutputStream fos = new  FileOutputStream("users.xml");
FileOutputStream fileos= getApplicationContext().openFileOutput(xmlFile, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = Xml.newSerializer();              
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
xmlSerializer.setOutput(writer);
xmlSerializer.startDocument("UTF-8", true);
xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "userData");
xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "userName");
xmlSerializer.text(username_String_Here);
xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "userName");
xmlSerializer.startTag(null,"password");
xmlSerializer.text(password_String);
xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "password");             
xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "userData");
xmlSerializer.endDocument();
xmlSerializer.flush();
String dataWrite = writer.toString();
fileos.write(dataWrite.getBytes());
fileos.close();
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IllegalStateException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Is that possible to store every user information in that file

Comment: What do you mean by every user information? Instead you can use [SQLite DB](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) to store user information.